# Samsung orsay/legacy tv remote web inspector on Windows 10

Tags: remote-debugging, samsung-smart-tv, web-inspector, inspector

I'm trying to use the Remote Web Inspector for Samsung Orsay (Legacy) TV for the 2012/2013/2014 years on Windows 10.
I'm trying to follow the official Guide (https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/legacy-platform-library/d44/index) and I've installed the Samsung SDK 5.1 for Win 64 bit, but the images/steps shown are completely different from the "real" SDK.

Can someone explane me how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So forgive me if i'm incorrect:
 - The legacy and the new IDE is still eclipse
 - Samsung made plugins for the IDE
 - For newer platform's these plugins will use SDB to connect to the device, install apps and etc...
 - SDB is almost ADB (Android Debug Bridge)
 - Therefor you can launch and app with arguments passed down to have the inspector

For older platforms these are a little bit different, they used to have a Smart Hub feature "User Sync".
The documentation says in order to use RWI you need to Sync the app from the same IP and access the RWI web GUI from that IP.
Therefore:

- Host an simple web server on port 80
- The root should contain: widgetlist.xml (localhost/widgetlist.xml)
- the xml should be like:

  yourappname


  http://yournetworkipOrdomain/widgets/yourappname.zip

and ofc the zip should be downloadable

- Then open the developer setting on the device, change the Server ip to your IP
- Select User Sync or App sync (may vary)
- App will install
- Launch the app
- Open your browser and access the RWI: http://tvip:7011

Enjoy :)

Comment: Please include the relevant reference in your answer, as the links may go stale in the future.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your response. I've already installed dev apps on Samsung Orsay 2012/2013/2014 (aka Samsung Legacy TV), but when I open http://tvip:7011 nothing is displayed. So, my answer is: is it necessary to do some particular action in order to enable the RWI on the TV? I've got actually a 2013 and 2014 TV, but I can only install dev apps without debugging (and sometimes it is really difficult to understand why a bug occurs).

Comment: I tried this but accessing the RWI: http://tvip:7011 shows "refused to connect.". I am on the same network as my device. and completed all steps. but still.

Comment: Any help on this please ?

Comment: did you find a way to debugg 2014 model ?

Answer (score 0):

For legacy devices such as Orsay. You can give a try to weinre debugger. Setup a debug server, and attach it to index.html in your app.

It allows seeing console.logs, and inspecting elements